# Java Code Generation based on compiled Class files

Tags: java, maven, compilation, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to generate a wrappers for POJO classes that will contain some additional functionalities.

So, for my case I need an ability to generate new java source code files based on compiled classes (PojoWrapper.java for Pojo.class).

But I have to use exactly class files. There are two reasons for that:

1. I need a final shape of the class, but annotation processors can change it. For example Lombok may add methods to the class, but for me it is important to know about those methods in advance.
2. I have to be able to generate source code for classes that I do not own (3rd party libraries).

Obviously, annotation-processing will not work for me.

The first idea that came to my mind was to make a maven plugin that will analyze generated binary classes via ASM library. And after that I will generate source code.

But here comes a tricky part: to get a final JAR I would need to compile my project two times, first time to generate a wrappers source code, and then I need to compile all files together to build a final binary.

Here I am thinking about a separate call to maven-compile-plugin, before compile phase, that will compile a subset of classes that I need, after that I will perform my code generation, and then on a compile phase the whole project will be compiled.

My question is: how to implement properly the following steps:

1. Compile a set of classes that will be a basis for code generation
2. Analyze binaries and generate java source code

Comment: Why do you need to recompile the decompiled code? Are you changing it? If so, then why not just change the original code? If not, then what do you hope to accomplish by decompiling and recompiling?

Comment: @JosephSible, I am not recompiling, but generating another source files (updated description, hope now it is more clear).

Comment: Does your code generation modify or extend the *API* of the code? Is there anything that doesn't compile before you generate your code? The answer to that greatly influences that answer to the question. If you don't change the API of the code, it's fine to do all code generation at the end. In fact, you may want to look into AOP tools like AspectJ to add your functionality, that may be simpler than doing all the bytecode manipulation yourself.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, my code generation will extend the API, but it should not touch existing classes, instead, I need to generate NEW source files based on compiled classes.

I have an example, imagine I need to build a source file that will contain list of fields that corresponds to every getter method in the class I want to use as a basis. I cannot use source code, because of Lombok, it will generate getter later, but I need to prepare a source file that will list getters and will be available for developers to write a code using generated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java Compiler Plugin API (i.e. intercept `javac` compiling phases).

See

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Plugin.html

https://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin

https://tutortrex.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/java-compiler-plug-ins-in-java-8-use-a-new-plug-in-mechanism-to-extend-the-java-compiler-with-new-behavior/

Comment: no, this will not work, I also need to analyze classes that come compiled, from 3rd party libs

Comment: So load these and analyze.

Comment: does plugin process also dependencies? and then, when I have new source files generated, is it possible to add them to ongoing compilation?

Comment: Plugin does whatever you write. You do not need to generate source files - you can generate class files directly like Lombok does

Comment: for my case I actually need java sources but not a bytecode

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: indeed, I want to give that code to developers so they can also use it

Comment: You can give it as a library.

Comment: I can try this way as well